# Regression as function of another variable

Tags: regression, least-squares

I'm trying to run a simple OLS where I have housing prices (in log prices) as the dependent variable and surface area (in log surface area), wall type, roof type and other characteristics as independent variables (all categorical so a different dummy variable for each type would be generated).

Given that the surface area is the main predictor of housing prices, I would like to set the coefficients of the other characteristics as a percentage of the surface area. For example, if the coefficient for the log surface area is 10, I would like to know by how much having a concrete wall increases/decreases the estimated housing price as a percentage of the log surface area.

I was thinking of running the following regression:
log(housing_value)=b0+b1*log(surface_area)+b2*log(surface_area)*wall=concrete+b3*log(surface_area)*wall=zinc+... but not sure if that would make sense statistically as I feel like I would need to also add the variables wall=concrete, wall=zinc, etc.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Nick--

"Given that the surface area is the main predictor of housing prices"

Location, location, location?

Comment: I don't think you need to or should change the model itself to set up the comparison you're after. Your features are naturally not on a common scale, and you can't change that. Instead, I would estimate what you believe to be the right model, then compare effect sizes by choosing meaningful pairs or sets of values for individual covariates, holding the others equal, and then comparing resulting estimates.